# Is there an equivalent of MonoDevelop's Document Outline in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, monodevelop

MonoDevelop has a Document Outline (Class Outline?) window that displays all variables, methods, and regions:

[image]

Is there an equivalent to this in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: VS 2012 has the Class View integrated with the file view. Drop a file down and it'll show you all the classes within it (and then class members). No support for regions though. This is the standard Solution Explorer window. Not to be confused with the "Document Outline" window on a WinForms design surface that shows you all controls in play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I had  the same question and my prefered solution is:*

**Jetbrains ReSharper** (8.0) has a **File Structure window** which shows the structure of the current file as tree (types/members) and regions are also supported.

Answer (score 2):

[Code Maid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) is a free Visual Studio extension that adds a `digging` window tool.

This will answer to your needs, I believe.

[image]

This tool also allow you to reorder code elements with drag & drop directly within this window.

Answer (score 1):

The solution explorer gives you most of this by default if you expand a class by clicking the little sideways arrow.

The icons and colours next to methods and variables indicate things like access level, return types etc

Comment: This is somewhat similar, albeit a lot more complex than what I'm looking for. Also, it doesn't display and organize regions.

Comment: You're right with the regions, it does most of the rest though

Answer (score 1):

There's `Class View` which can be opened from the `View` menu (CTRL + SHIFT + C)

It's not exactly the same as the image you've provided but it's very similar.

Comment: The Class View doesn't do the same thing, it doesn't show the class's properties and regions.

Comment: The regions aren't shown but the class' properties are. There's two parts to the Class View. The top part shows the class in a tree view whilst the second part (below for me) shows the properties, fields, methods etc.